# Angular keeps automatically reloading

Tags: angular, macos, angular-cli, macos-high-sierra

Angular keeps automatically reloading when using:

> ng serve
>   This behaviour only happens on my computer.

iMac Late 2013
OS: OSX High Sierra

Answer (score 9):

I had the project in my Documents folder which is synced to iCloud.
'ng serve' would reload when iCloud syncs the project folder.

Solution: Move the project out of the iCloud folder.

This took me a lot of time to figure out, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Saved me a lot of headache

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem turned out to be the port I was using. It took me forever to figure it out because I had been using that port `4202` for that app for a long time. But suddenly it was causing this issue. I served the app on a different port and it worked fine. I could find nothing on my system (Ubuntu 22.10) using that port, so I have no idea how that was manifesting itself.